# Entity framework add multiple collections to collection with one query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Imagine the following scenario...
I have an array that contains keywords:

```
string[] keywords= new string[] { "someKeyword", "otherKeyword", "andAnother One"};
```

In my database I have a table for news articles. Each news article has a title, that is one of the keywords.

I want to get all the news articles that contain the keywords from the array with one query.

At the moment I iterate the keywords and run a query fore every item in it:

```
List<NewsArticle> allArticles = new List<NewsArticle>();

foreach (var key in keywords)
{
    var articles = db.NewsArticle.FindAllAsync(x => x.Title = key).Result;
    allArticles.Add(articles);
}
```

This works, but I am getting data with keywords.Length queries. I am trying to get the data with one query.
Something like the following:

```
var newsArticles = db.NewsArticle.All().Where(a => keywords.Any(k => k.Equals(a.Title)));
```

or

```
var newsArticles = from a in db.NewsArticles.All()
                   join k in keywords on NewsArticle.Title equals k
                   select a;
```

Is it possible to get it with one query, and if so how?

- Note the above examples did not work.

Comment: I haven't seen `All()` before. What does it do?

Comment: I don't see any major issues with the LINQ query you have here. You say that "it does not work". Could you explain why it does not work?

Comment: All is coming from the Generic Repository pattern, which I am using.

Comment: It is not working as I get the following error both with my Linq query and the suggested one by user Mahesh Chand: "The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'."

Comment: You have to be more specific. I don't know the "generic repository pattern". Could you show the implementation of `All`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use following linq:

```
var newsArticles = (from a in db.NewsArticles
               where keywords.Contains(a.Title)
               select a).ToList();
```

Comment: I am getting the following exception: The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'. I do not know where are 'OrderBy' and 'Skip' coming from.

Comment: Can you please show the code how are you using Skip() method? You can try the updated answer.

Comment: The thing is that I am not using neither Skip() nor OrderBy()

Comment: What's there in method db.NewsArticles.All()?

Comment: Could you please try without using .All(). please see my updated answer

Comment: I found the problem. In the end I was calling a method newsArticles.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize); ToPagedList comes from a NuGet package called "PageList". This was the problem. Your query works